# StackExchange as a community welfare website

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Given the fact that a lots of countries in South East Asia have deplorable conditions regarding the situation of law and order(which effectively means that it takes years of legal battles to get justice), can this website be used as a platform to help such needy people effectively in a cheap manner?

Answer (score 6):

Not directly.

If you're thinking of something like "legal aid" for individual cases then, as you point out, the lack of law and order itself would stymie any such effort even if Law.SE could be used to "crowd-source" legal assistance (which, for the record, it seems pretty clear that it both can't and won't).

If you think this might be a great place to draw attention to legal problems then you could do much better.  This is a Q&A site, not a discussion or advocacy site.  If you ask a great question that somehow draws attention to a real-world problem then maybe you'll have made a little progress, but nothing like you could by starting an account on a social networking site where you can aggregate interest and information with the intent of calling attention and action to the problem.

Only if the source of legal disorder were a lack of very specific information could this site help.  But again, in addition to political literature and philosophy on the subject there are countless organizations (and, one might argue, countries and treaties) devoted to improving the rule of law throughout the world.

Answer (score 3):

Without coming off as kind of mean, . . .

**How? Why?**

[We are not here to give legal advice.](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7/how-will-we-discourage-people-asking-for-or-giving-legal-advice-in-law). The questions and answers here deal with hypothetical situations, not specific events. The only way to do as you say would be to address specific situations. Everyone's circumstances are different, even in places where, overall, things are crummy.

Southeast Asia is also not the only place where there are, in terms of the legal situation, "deplorable conditions". North Korea - to cite an example that I think many people can agree with - is a start.

There are laws in other countries that many people think are unfair. Controversial issues abound, and just because person A thinks a system is wrong doesn't mean that person B thinks it's wrong. Should we also turn to areas where the legal rights of women are not the same as those of men (and there are lots of those places)? Is it our job to interfere? No. That is not the goal of Stack Exchange.

Finally, I have to go back to "How?" How can one website - filled with many without much legal experience - help in any significant way? What do you propose we do?

Again, I hate to come across as harsh, . . . but I don't quite see how or why we could do this.